# Pyramid: Overwrite Routing Rules Based on User Status

Tags: python, url-routing, pyramid

I am working on a small Pyramid web application (Python). One requirement is that the user resets the password after a fixed period of time, say, once a year. (I don't consider this requirement to help in terms of security, however, the customer's internal policy requires it.)

The password update should take place after a successful login. It is easy to add the logic to display the update password dialog after the login, but it is also possible that the user just navigates away using a bookmarked URL or the like.

What I would need to do is to overwrite the routing rules based on a property of the logged in user. However, the routing configuration seems to be just a set of static rules in Pyramid.

Is there a way to overwrite the routing rules based on the user's state, so that all requests to other views are forwarded/redirected to the password update dialog?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution using [Pyramid events](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/api/events.html):

```
from pyramid.events import NewRequest, subscriber

@subscriber(NewRequest)
def intercept(event):
    # use event.request to check if an interception/redirect is required
    raise HTTPFound(location='route_to_form')
```

It is important to check the incoming request thoroughly. For example, paths including the route being used further in the process must be excluded, otherwise the application ends up in an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have class based views and that you have set a session variable `is_password_recent` which is `True` if less than one year ago, you could put the following into each class's `__init__()`:

```
class UserViews:
    def __init__(self, request):
        self.request = request

        if not request.session["is_password_recent"]:
            raise HTTPFound(
                location=request.route_url(
                    "password_renew", _query={"return": request.path}
                )
            )
```

You could probably DRY it, too, by putting the logic into a method in a `utils` module and import it.

Comment: The `raise HTTPFound()`, as opposed to `return HTTPFound()`, which I tried before, saved me. Thank you!